# How do I vertically align these Html 5 progress bars?

Tags: html

I have a series of progress bars each with name, I want them to be vertically aligned so that the progress bar starts at the same place on each line. I could use tables to do this, but what is the preferred way to do this.

```html
<div><label for="pb0">Processing</label><progress id="pb0" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb1">Songs loaded</label><progress id="pb1" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb3">Songs ignored because already matched</label><progress id="pb3" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb13">Songs updated from Naim metadata </label><progress id="pb13" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb4">Songs matched to MusicBrainz release</label><progress id="pb4" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb5">Songs matched to MusicBrainz song only</label><progress id="pb5" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb14">Songs matched to Acoustid song only</label><progress id="pb14" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb7">Songs matched with artwork</label><progress id="pb7" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb17">Songs matched to AcousticBrainz</label><progress id="pb17" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb8">Songs saved (if not preview)</label><progress id="pb8" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb11">Completed</label><progress id="pb11" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb12">Errors</label><progress id="pb12" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        </div>
```

Comment: Float: right for all the progress bars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float:right`, and `margin-right` to align with the position you want.

```css
progress{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label for="pb0">Processing</label><progress id="pb0" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb1">Songs loaded</label><progress id="pb1" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb3">Songs ignored because already matched</label><progress id="pb3" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb13">Songs updated from Naim metadata </label><progress id="pb13" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    ...
</div>
```

Or, you can work with your label:

```css
label{
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label for="pb0">Processing</label><progress id="pb0" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb1">Songs loaded</label><progress id="pb1" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb3">Songs ignored because already matched</label><progress id="pb3" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb13">Songs updated from Naim metadata </label><progress id="pb13" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    ...
</div>
```

And, without cutting the text (just set one min-width for your label):

```css
label{
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label for="pb0">Processing</label><progress id="pb0" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb1">Songs loaded</label><progress id="pb1" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb3">Songs ignored because already matched</label><progress id="pb3" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    <label for="pb13">Songs updated from Naim metadata </label><progress id="pb13" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
    ...
</div>
```

Or, you can use `display: flex`:

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

label, progress{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="pb0">Processing</label><progress id="pb0" value="0" max="200"></progress>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="pb1">Songs loaded</label><progress id="pb1" value="0" max="200"></progress>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="pb3">Songs ignored because already matched</label><progress id="pb3" value="0" max="200"></progress>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="pb13">Songs updated from Naim metadata </label><progress id="pb13" value="0" max="200"></progress>
</div>
    ...
```

Comment: Easy and good, just to mention this works as long as the div arround is big enough to handle it.

Comment: Thanks but does this mean that the progress bar is shifted simply so its ends 50 pixels from the right edge of the screen. that would be a large gap would be between label and progress bar ?

Comment: But you can edit it. Just need to work with the width of your entire div.

Comment: Oh i see so you set width of surrounding div to not be entire width of screen. Okay, but there not a way to simply say align progress bar so the left handside all starts at the same place because Im rendering this code in Java and for different users they could have the text in different languages and hence the length of label could vary so hardcoding progressbar to be same distance from right handside is not going to work well.

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block` and use some overflow configuration. See the updated code.

Comment: Now its cutting off the text label, i think my point is that you seem to have to hardcode the width (e,g 100px), so actually is the best thing to do in this case use table, tr, and td

Comment: I've told you to use `overflow` to make it dynamic and don't break your display... but you can remove it from the code.You can work with `table` tag, but everything you do with the `tr` and `tr` is less maintanable than with your good CSS features.

Comment: thx for your help but why havent you used overflow, why would I not want it dynamic. I'm well aware of the mantra that CSS is more maintable than using table but your answer seems to indicate otherwise, you say I have to manually set min-width for a label, well that is not maintainable. Maybe the last example where you have used flex would be the best option, but all the others seem like hacks to me.

Comment: Sometimes you need to prevent the size from becoming smaller. Otherwise, it would become illegible.
I was only giving you examples for what you can do. If you want to remove one property, you decide.

Comment: Im sorry I dont see this is better than using a table, maybe the flex option is the correct option but all the others are just hacks. I think the issue is that without using  a table  the css does not realize that all the progress bar labels and all the progress bars shod be aligned

Comment: Then you can interpret the css as a "hack". Separate the labels and progress bars in divs, they will become "cells of a table".

Comment: but okay yes i think table or divs are necessary to do this properly but i will mark your answer correct as it gives good background info.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate it:

Webkit: -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

FireFox: -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

IE: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);

Answer (score 0):

You can assign width to label based on your need.

```css
label{
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><label for="pb0">Processing</label><progress id="pb0" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb1">Songs loaded</label><progress id="pb1" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb3">Songs ignored because already matched</label><progress id="pb3" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb13">Songs updated from Naim metadata </label><progress id="pb13" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb4">Songs matched to MusicBrainz release</label><progress id="pb4" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb5">Songs matched to MusicBrainz song only</label><progress id="pb5" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb14">Songs matched to Acoustid song only</label><progress id="pb14" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb7">Songs matched with artwork</label><progress id="pb7" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb17">Songs matched to AcousticBrainz</label><progress id="pb17" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb8">Songs saved (if not preview)</label><progress id="pb8" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb11">Completed</label><progress id="pb11" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        <label for="pb12">Errors</label><progress id="pb12" value="0" max="200"></progress><br>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good but dont quite get it, what does  50% correspond to , 50% of what ?

Comment: `50%` of parent `<div>` you can adjust it based on your need, even you can change the value in different resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one rule css,

```
progress { float: right;}
```